# unitialized subscription while replicating database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, database-replication

Getting this warning when trying to setup a transactional replication. This error occurs when setting up a subscription from `sql server express` using non impersonated login to the distributor. this works using `sql server developer` subscrption to `sql server workgroup` publication but not from `sql express` to `sql workgroup`. Im not sure if it is an issue with the agent or what not but the subscription setup is identical to my working subscription other than the ability to choose the login to the sql server agent.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, you're trying to use SQL Server Express as your publisher. SQL Server Express can only be a subscriber in a transactional replication.

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compare-features.aspx#integration

Comment: no im using workgroup as a publisher and sql express to subscribe